# How to implement RecycerView With Items having Radio buttons with single choice mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to show a **recyclerview with single choice** item. but Recyclerview doesn't have the choice mode.

Does any one know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can we help you if you didnt post codes ?

Answer (score 2):

Store the `states` of the checked items in a `SparseBooleanArray` with the position as key.As you change the `state` of the `button`,update it's status in the `booleanArray` and call `notifyItemChanged(position)`.And in `BindviewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder,int position)` method load the state from `booleanArray` like `viewholder.radioButton.setChecked(boolean.get(position))`.Have a look at [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/statelistdrawables-for-recyclerview-selection/) for basic idea

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, it stores position for selected item, you could add a bit more code to store the item itself if your adapter reorders itself

```
public class SingleChoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SingleChoiceAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private static final int NO_POSITION = -1;
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION = "SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION";

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<Item> items;

    private int selectedItemPosition = NO_POSITION;

    public SingleChoiceAdapter(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            selectedItemPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION, NO_POSITION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item.name);
        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(position == selectedItemPosition
                ? Color.LTGRAY
                : Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateSelectedItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Item getSelectedItem() {
        if (selectedItemPosition == NO_POSITION) {
            return null;
        }
        return items.get(selectedItemPosition);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION, selectedItemPosition);
    }

    private void updateSelectedItem(int newSelectedItemPosition) {
        if (selectedItemPosition != NO_POSITION) {
            notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition);
        }
        selectedItemPosition = newSelectedItemPosition;
        notifyItemChanged(newSelectedItemPosition);
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView textView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Displaying already checks**-

You can maintain a boolean array of size of your list. On bind view handle the boolean(true/ false) logic, like setting check true/false of a radio button.

**Handling new clicks**-

Then on the onclick of the radio button, set the value of every array element to false and setting the current array position to true after that. Now call `notifyDatatSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it with just one single integer variable instead of maintaining an array which is costly in devices like android where space is a constraint.

So, just maintain a single integer variable, lets say int **selectedPosition=-1** initially.
In onBind check if the **position==selectedPosition**, if true check the button else uncheck.
Whenever user checks/unchecks the button, just update the **selectedPosition**

Something like this,

```
if(selectedPosition==position)
   selectedPosition=-1
else{
   selectedPosition=position
   notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
}
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the id for the position in `onBindViewHolder` then you can process action in this method too. Update data set and call `notifyDataSetChanged`

[image: The result as below]

Here is my example code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemObject itemObject = mDataset.get(position);
    ((ViewHolder)holder).mTextView.setText(itemObject.getTitle());
    Button mButton = ((ViewHolder) holder).mButton;


    mButton.setSelected(itemObject.isSelected());
    if(itemObject.isSelected()){

        ((ViewHolder)holder).mTextView.setText("OK");
    }
    mButton.setTag(position);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDatset((Integer) v.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

In the updateDataset method, I update information of this dataset and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Good luck